# Zero a column in a csv file with awk while skipping the header

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I would like to zero one column of a csv file. Let's assume the csv file looks like this:

```
col1|col2|col3
v   |  54| t
a   |  25| f
d   |  53| f
s   |  04| t
```

Using awk this way, gives me almost what I want

command:

```
awk -F'|' -v OFS='|'  '$2=0.0;7' input.csv > output.csv
```

the result

```
col1|0|col3
v   |0| t
a   |0| f
d   |0| f
s   |0| t
```

But notice that the column header has been also zeroed which is something I am trying to avoid. So I tried to skip the first line with the awk command but I am getting an empty file

```
awk -F'|' -v OFS='|'  'NR<1 {exit} {$5=0.0;7}' input.csv > output.csv
```

What am I missing?

Comment: why do you have a seven there? seems like a typo...

Comment: @Ismael check the comment of user112638726 in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just apply the rule from the 2nd line on with a `NR>1 {}`:

```
$ awk -F'|' -v OFS='|'  'NR>1{$2=0.0}7' file
col1|col2|col3
v   |0| t
a   |0| f
d   |0| f
s   |0| t
```

Why wasn't your approach `awk -F'|' -v OFS='|'  'NR<1 {exit} {$5=0.0;7}'`working?

The expression `NR<1{exit}` is never True because NR is always at least 1.

This means that the second expression `{$5=0.0;7}` is always evaluated. The `$5=0.0` is fine, but `7` is not printing as you would want to, because to print a line you need some kind of `print` instruction. It would work if you moved the `7` outside the braces, so that it will evaluate to True and the record will be printed: `awk -F'|' -v OFS='|'  'NR<1 {exit} {$5=0.0}7'`.

But this wouldn't do what you want. Instead, you may want to say `NR==1 {next}` to skip the first line. However, this will prevent it from being printed:

```
$ awk -F'|' -v OFS='|'  'NR==1{next} $2=0.0;7' file
v   |0| t
a   |0| f
d   |0| f
s   |0| t
```

Comment: This is the right answer to resolve my issue, thanks. I will accept it when I can.

Comment: @MedAli You also seem to not quite understand what `7` does in this context. As it is non zero it is seen as awk as true. The same goes for `$2=0.0` but it is seen as false. So technically your first command(in the question) is seen as  `'$2=0.0{print $0};7{print $0}'` or  `'false{print $0};true{print $0}`.

Comment: @User112638726, thank you. Now I do understand what 7 stands for :)

Answer (score 2):

Change `exit` to `next` to skip the remaining actions for that first line.

Comment: I did that, but the resulting file is empty